# In a google glass why are past events moved to right of the main menu?

Tags: design, google-glass, wearables

Generally in a time line users would image past events to be on the left, current events in the center and future on their right.But Google glass's timeline seems to be little intriguing as it has past events on the right.Is there any reason behind its design? or is my assumption of a timeline wrong?

Example ([or watch a video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfs5d00TNrA)):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used Google Glass but I'd imagine that since the cards feel like a band around the head, then swiping backwards should feel like you're physically swiping the cards into the past (as if to throw them behind you) in order to be able to see what's coming up.

Conversely swiping forwards has to do the opposite.

So it's probably a mistake to see it as a traditional timeline. It's not. Better to see the cards as real interactive content and let them naturally relate to how they are presented and the swipe actions available. Another example of **the content is the interface**?

Have you used glass? Does it feel wrong? I doubt it!

Comment: Yeah i have used glass, you need to swipe forward for past events and backward for present and future events which I felt was a little odd..I would always imagine future events to my right..

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making comparison with how timeline is being presented in real life.

You could ask the same question why Facebook, Google+, or any other timeline based apps, present the latest event at the top and past events below.

First and foremost, in designing how information is being presented to the user, ***we need to understand what the user is most interested in***. In such apps, our user is most interested with latest event, which would then be presented first in the list, be it horizontal or vertical. Past events are usually of second importance level, which would then be listed in reverse chronological order after the first in the list.

Reading top-down and left-right are the most natural way (except for RTL languages). So you'd then present your information from latest to oldest in top-down or left-right manner.

You can definitely refer to how Windows 8 apps present information horizontally.

On a side note, when looking at historical timeline, you're usually more interested to find out how something started and got to the way it is/was eventually. Hence, oldest to latest in left-right or top-bottom manner.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Your view is perfectly valid.. What confused me was in usual timelines you l always be on top say the latest and then you move down.. But here you are in the middle..and not with the latest happening..

Comment: May i know what's to the left of the Now card? Is it related information? Or its just something that's totally irrelevant?

Comment: It is relevant information..the current and future events..